# How to immobilize the AI in Age of Empires 2 HD?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-hd

I'm making a scenario and I want to completely immobilize the AI. There were several personalities available in the list, including some entries with 'immobilize' or something, which I selected.

But now the AI does move. How to immobilize all AI units?

Comment: [The Ultimate Scenario Designer's Guide](https://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/914421-age-of-empires-ii-the-conquerors-expansion/faqs/24505)

Answer (score 1):

Don't quote me on this, as I may be thinking of AoE1, but there was a personality type of "none" in which they would only perform scripted actions. If this exists in AoEHD, try it out.

If not, I think that the "triggers" menu could help, if you know how to work it.